# Can i accept events from Bus by Fragment?

Tags: android, event-bus

I'm using Otto EventBus. I have an RecyclerViewAdapter where i'm using Bus.post method when item clicked, problem is that fragment where i have a recylcer view is not accepting event, so i have no reaction when item is clicked, i registering Bus in Activity where replacing fragments and Activity is successfully accepting events, but fragment - no, so can i register fragment for listening events or i should use callback?

BusProvider class :

```
 public final class BusProvider {

    private static final Bus BUS = new Bus();

    public static Bus getInstance() {
        return BUS;
    }

    private BusProvider(){}
}
```

ViewHolderOnClick code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    transfers.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    BusProvider.getInstance().post(new OnButtonDeleteClickEvent(transfers.isEmpty(), id));
                    break;
}
```

Fragment Subscribe method

```
@Subscribe
    public void onButtonDeleteClick(OnButtonDeleteClickEvent event) {
        db.deleteTransfer(event.getId());
        if (event.isListEmpty()) {
            setVisibility(false);
        }
        CustomToast toast = new CustomToast(getActivity(), getString(R.string.successfully_deleted));
        toast.show();
    }
```

I'm using correct @Subscribe, and event works when i using it in activity

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call `register` method of event bus. Please check below snippet to init and deinit EventBus subscriptions.

I am subscribing to EventBus whenever `View` is created as I am interested to listen messages/events only when my UI is visible. So I take advantage of `onViewCreated` method of a `fragment`.

```
   @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   }
```

And don't forgot to remove subscriptions when UI is not visible anymore.

```
   @Override
   public void onDestroyView() {
       super.onDestroyView();
       EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
   }
```